# WebScraping Next pages with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

When I navigate to the below link and locate the pagination at the bottom of the page:
https://shop.nordstrom.com/c/sale-mens-clothing?origin=topnav&breadcrumb=Home%2FSale%2FMen%2FClothing&sort=Boosted

I am only able to scrape the first 4 or so pages then my script stops

I have tried with xpath, css_selector, and with the WebDriverWait options

```
 pages_remaining = True
 page = 2   //starts @ page 2 since page one is scraped already with first loop



 while pages_remaining:

      //scrape code

      try:
           wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
           wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, str(page)))).click()

           print browser.current_url
           page += 1

     except TimeoutException:
           pages_remaining = False
```

Current Results from console:

```
 https://shop.nordstrom.com/c/sale-mens-designer-clothing-accessories-  shoes?breadcrumb=Home%2FSale%2FMen%2FDesigner&page=2&sort=Boosted

 https://shop.nordstrom.com/c/sale-mens-designer-clothing-accessories-shoes?breadcrumb=Home%2FSale%2FMen%2FDesigner&page=3&sort=Boosted

 https://shop.nordstrom.com/c/sale-mens-designer-clothing-accessories-shoes?breadcrumb=Home%2FSale%2FMen%2FDesigner&page=4&sort=Boosted
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a BeautifulSoup one, because I am not too familiar with Selenium.

Try to create a new variable with your number of pages. As you can see, when you enter the next page the URL changes, thus just manipulate the given URL. See my code example below.

```
# Define variable pages first
pages = [str(i) for i in range(1,53)] # 53 'cuz you have 52 pages

for page in pages:
    response = get("https://shop.nordstrom.com/c/sale-mens-clothing?origin=topnav&breadcrumb=Home%2FSale%2FMen%2FClothing&page=" + page + "&sort=Boosted"
# Rest of you code
```

This snippet should do the job for the rest of the pages. Hope that helps, although this might not exactly what you have been looking for.

When you have any questions just post below. ;).

Cheers.

Comment: Not totally what I was looking for since I would have to manually adjust the page range based on how many pages are displayed but the solution is working after twerking it to fit my code

Answer (score 1):

You could loop throught page numbers until no more results are shown by just changing the url:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

base_url = "https://m.shop.nordstrom.com/c/sale-mens-clothing?origin=topnav&breadcrumb=Home%2FSale%2FMen%2FClothing&page={}&sort=Boosted"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

page = 1
soup = BeautifulSoup("")

#Will loop untill there's no more results
while "Looks like we don’t have exactly what you’re looking for." not in soup.text:
    print(base_url.format(page))
    #Go to page
    driver.get(base_url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

    ### your extracting code

    page +=1
```

Comment: Thanks and def like the logic above. However, when I used the above code and keep getting a UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 24: ordinal not in range(128). I cannot find the issue.

Comment: Do you have the full traceback? Do not have this error on my side